# how to use pivot table in python pandas for below input?

Tags: python, pandas

Input:(status_df)

ID         status

1        matched
 2        not matched
 3        matched
 4        matched
 5        unknown
 6        not matched
 7        not matched
 8        matched
 9        unknown
10        unknown

after pivot(i want count for values in separate column and grand total at last row )

**count of status**
**status**      **Total**

matched              4
not matched      3
unknown              3
**Grand Total**    10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counter, then add new value by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s = status_df['status'].value_counts()
s.loc['Grand Total'] = s.sum()
print (s)
matched         4
unknown         3
not matched     3
Grand Total    10
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

Then convert to 2 columns `DataFrame` and create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = s.rename_axis('status').reset_index(name='Total')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['count of status'], df.columns])
print (df)
   count of status      
           status Total
0         matched     4
1         unknown     3
2     not matched     3
3     Grand Total    10
```

Comment: Thank you very much..almost i got the near solution but how to get headings same like specified

Comment: still i'm getting column headings like previously..those rename_axis and MultiIndex code lines are not affecting i think

Comment: @PraveenTallapalli - Are you sure? If change `print (df.columns)` before and after `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['count of status'], df.columns])` it is same?